# Aletheia equivalent for Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, tesseract

Is there a ubuntu-linux equivalent to windows Aletheia, a program to analyze fonts, export points to xml? Mainly I would use it for OCR and training tesseract. I understand that ImageMagick can cover lot's of the ground for image cleanup. I need a tool for character substitution and other features as in Aletheia –

Comment: I did a search, but did not find any tool by that name.  Can you provide a more comprehensive description of its features and what you need it to do?  A link to the program homepage would also be helpful.

Comment: pls look at the https://www.primaresearch.org/tools/Aletheia/Editions link for a list of features the programs offers.

Comment: Mainly I would use it for OCR and training tesseract. I understand that ImageMagick can cover lot's of the ground for image cleanup. I need a tool for character substitution and other features as in Aletheia

Comment: I have no idea how to train Tesseract. I guess you can try running it in Wine or VM. Can you edit your question to include the info you typed in the comments?